# Why do I have to update to the most recent iOS version?

Tags: ios, upgrade, iphone

I have an iPhone 4s that is still running iOS 5.1.1. Why is it not possible for me to update my device to  a newer version of ios without going all the way to the latest?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to upgrade to iOS 8?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Because that's Apple's update policy.

Longer answer: Maintaining and supporting several major iOS versions is a lot of work, even if the older versions would just get security fixes. It's not just about the source code, any update also needs testing, dealing with apps which may break, update of various support documents etc. So you get both new functionality *and* security fixes by staying with the most recent version. In your case, running iOS 8 on an 4S actually works quite fine.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has decided to remove previous versions when a new (replacement) is released.

You could scan the web and find other versions from someone else but not from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

The same reason why nobody takes Samsung and HTC seriously: if your device can handle the latest but you won't update to the latest, you're just going to miss out on features and optimizations. You also risk your security and the security of others.
Because there are very few situations where you should be on any older than the latest version your system can handle, Apple instructs iTunes and OTA updates to use the latest ROM available for the device.
If you want a newer but old version so badly, hack your iTunes.